# How to retrieve quoted text between html tags?

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, geb

I am trying to automate GUI tests for a legacy webpage using groovy/geb in Eclipse and for some reason part of the pages html is built very differently which is resulting in what normally works to get text inside tags to not work. Also am using geckodriver and firefox.
Below is a very simplified example of what I am dealing with.

How the html looks when inspecting elements in browser:

```
...
<div>
<td class="RowLabelPopup">
" Name: "
</td>
<span class="RowValue">Bob Smith</span>
<td class="RowLabelPopup">Address:</td>
<span class="RowValue">123 that st</span>
</div>
...
```

How I have setup the navigators to elements in the pageobject:

```
nameLabel {$("td.RowLabelPopup")[0]}
nameValue {$("span.RowValue")[0]}
addressLabel {$("td.RowLabelPopup")[1]}
addressValue {$("span.RowValue")[1]}
```

How I am attempting to check those elements in my spec:

```
nameLabel.text() == " Name: " //fails as nameLabel.text() returns ""
nameValue.text() == "Bob Smith"
addressLabel.text() == "Address:"
addressValue.text() == "123 that st"
```

I have tried .value(), checking if the text is considered a child of nameLabel
Why does .text() not work for the nameLabel but it works for everything else and how can I retrieve this text?

Comment: You're grabbing $("td.RowLabelPopup")[0] is there anything at $("td.RowLabelPopup")[1] say?

Comment: `<td>` for styling inside a div...  *shudder*.  Mike's right though, you probably have some other RowLabelPopup thats first in the list

Comment: I have used td.RowLabelPopup to search for elements and there is only 2 on this section. My overly simplified example hides the fact that the div is inside a table with an ID that I am searching within so any td.RowLabelPopup outside this table are ignored.  I was hoping there was just some trick I had missed about finding text in quotes...never seen pages built with this before

Answer (score 0):

> My overly simplified example hides the fact that the div is inside a table with an ID

Really? When I tried to reproduce your problem, I only succeeded when I put your snippet on a page outside of a `table`, because in this case the two `td`s without a parent yield empty navigators and therefore no text either. They are simply not found in the DOM.

As soon as I put your snippet into a `table`, it worked:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <div>
      <td class="RowLabelPopup">
        " Name: "
      </td>
      <span class="RowValue">Bob Smith</span>
      <td class="RowLabelPopup">Address:</td>
      <span class="RowValue">123 that st</span>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It even continued working when removing the `tr` element, putting the `div` directly inside the `table`. But of course, your condition must change from `nameLabel.text() == " Name: "` to `nameLabel.text() == '" Name: "'` in order to account for the double quotes.

I agree with Tim, however: Wrapping table cells and `span`s inside a `div` is super ugly and looks just wrong.